# sed to replace comma and new line

Tags: linux, ksh

I'm trying to replace this

```
colb,
cola,
)
```

with this

```
colb,
cola
)
```

in sed, but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried both of these but nothing seems to happen

```
sed -e  's/, \n)/\n)/g'

sed -e  's/,\n)/\n)/g'
```

I can get a new line to replace but I can't get a comma followed by a newline followed by ) to replace with just a newline followed by )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed

Comment: I can do a newline...I just can't get a comma with a new line to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending on the solution from [near-duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed), this does work:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n)/\
)/g'
```